# Next.js - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I know there are many questions regarding this error, I've gone through all that I could find.

I think it may have something to do with a lack of getInitialState but I'm not sure how i'd implement it.

I'm trying to create a dynamic list of text files within a folder, pulling information from the file itself through the frontMatter module.

```
import React from 'react'
import frontMatter from 'front-matter'
import fs from 'fs'

import { getFileList } from '../util/utils'

export default class DList extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps () {

    return getFileList('./static/filecontainer/').then((files) => {
      const linkParams = files.nameList.map((fileName, i) => {
        const content = fs.readFileSync(files.pathList[i], 'utf-8')
        const meta = frontMatter(content)
        return {
          name: fileName,
          title: meta.attributes.title,
          date: meta.attributes.date,
          description: meta.attributes.description,
        }
      })
      return {
        linkParams: linkParams
      }
    })
  }

    render () {
      return (
        <div id="listContainer">
            {
              this.props.linkParams.map((el, i) => {
                return (
                  <div className="itemBlock">
                    <div id="nameBlock"><div id='tFileTitle'>{el.title}</div><div id='tFileDate'>{el.date}</div></div>
                    <div id="descriptBlock"><p className='tFileInfo'>{el.description}</p></div>
                  </div>
                )
              })
            }
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Here's the `getFileList` function:

```
import yaml from 'js-yaml'

export async function getFileList (dirname) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir (dirname, (error, files) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        files.reverse()
        resolve({
          pathList: files.map( el => dirname + el ),
          nameList: files.map( el => el.slice(0, -3) )
        })
      }
    })
  })
}
```

So the idea is this would create a small box displaying all the information that I could then import into its own div on the main page.

```
import Header from '../components/Header'
import DList from '../components/DList'

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <div id="contentWrap">
      <div id="leftContent"><DList /></div>
      <div id="rightContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: *"The getFileList function can be found here: https://pastebin.com/T8uCWSTk"* Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *(I've put it in the question for you.)*

Comment: *"Next.js - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"* There are two calls to `.map` in your first quoted code block. Which one results in the error?!

Comment: so, WHICH of the four instances of `.map` is failing

Answer (score 1):

Your `DList` `render` function is using `this.props.linkParams.map`. Your *use* of `DList` is just `<DList />`, it doesn't set any properties at all, so `this.props.linkParams` is `undefined`. You need to either pass `linkParams` as a property when you use `DList` (`<DList linkParams={/*...*/} />`), or have `render` handle it if there is no `linkParams` property.

> I think it may have something to do with a lack of getInitialState

No, state and properties are different things. `state` is the state of the component, managed by the component. `props` are properties passed to the component by its user.

Comment: Ah, so I can't have getFileList create linkParams within the DLink class?

Comment: @AdenLaken: You could, but then you'd probably want to store it as state, and if you're populating the state asynchronously (as I think you want to?), you'd want `render` to handle the possibility that it doesn't have `this.state.linkParams` yet.

Comment: I see, how would I go about storing it as a state? Not sure how big of an explanation that would take so if you know of any tutorials or an example anywhere I'm happy to try learn it myself.

Comment: @AdenLaken: Take a look at the [State and Lifecycle docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and after that the [Lifting state up tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up). :-)